# Migrating from C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, dataset, resultset

I would love to know what does this line means:

```
 diferencias.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dif_cpu"].ToString()
```

Does this mean that I get the first row from the column dif_cpu?. Thanks so much.

Comment: means: get the first row/record and column `dif_cpu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diferencias.Tables[0].Rows[0]["dif_cpu"].ToString()
```

It'll convert the contents of cell in first row and under column `dif_cpu` to string.

[image]

The contents of cell marked with `X` will be used.

Answer (score 2):

It gets the first Table of the DataSet, selects the first Row of the dif_cpu Column and Converts the value to  a string.